# how to checkout git branches jenkins gui edits of last 5 days from master repo

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit-trigger, sonar-gerrit

Team,

I am trying to search for a string that was checked by a user by manually editing jenkins gui configuration . whenever we save this gui configuration, there is a direct commit to master on gerrit. Now, I want to search all the last 3 days of commits that happened to see who made that.

so when i do below, it takes for ever to download all days may be 30days of commits.

```
git clone ssh://git.team.com:29111/jenkins_configuration
```

is there a paraeter here i can say

```
--since 3d
```

such that it downloads only those commits and saves some time?

output:

```
Cloning into 'jenkins_configuration'...
remote: Counting objects: 204746,
```

expected output

```
Cloning into 'jenkins_configuration' last 3 day commits...
remote: Counting objects: xxx,
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Git command you can execute:

```
git clone --shallow-since=<date> ...
```

But if you are using the Git plugin on Jenkins you don't have the "shallow-since" parameter, only the "depth" one, so you need to choose a fixed number of commits (not days). It's equivalent to the following Git command:

```
git clone --depth <depth> ...
```